# Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference

Tags: perl

As an exercise, I'm trying to implement a stack to calculate postfix expressions.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my %operators = (
    '+' => \&sum,
    '-' => \&subs,
    '*' => \&mul,
    '/' => \&div,
);

print 'Enter an expression to evaluate : ';
chomp($_ = <STDIN>);
my @lettres=split(//);

my @stack;

for(my $i = 0; $i < @lettres; $i++){
    if(looks_like_number($lettres[$i])){
        unshift @stack, $lettres[$i];
    } else {
        my $nb1 = shift @stack;
        my $nb2 = shift @stack;
        unshift @stack, $operators{$lettres[$i]}->($nb1,$nb2);
    }
}

print 'Answer : ' .shift @stack;

sub sum { return $_[0] + $_[1];}
sub mul { return $_[0] * $_[1];}
sub subs { return $_[0] - $_[1];}
sub div { return $_[0] / $_[1];}
```

When running it, I got:

```
Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference at polonaise.pl line 25,
<STDIN> line 1.
```

Line 25 is:

```
unshift @stack, $operators{$lettres[$i]}->($nb1,$nb2);
```

I suspect that `$operators{$lettres[$i]}->($nb1,$nb2);` is causing the issue but I don't know why since I begin with Perl.

Why this happens and how can I fix that?

Comment: It means `$operators{$lettres[$i]}` returned undef.

Comment: @ikegami I see now. It's because I enter `8 6 2 - / 3 +` as input, so I'm getting empty spaces in the `letters` array. Also is there any better way to do it? Like just creating just one function which takes also the operator as parameter? My first implementation was using a switch but since it was not supported, I used this approach.

Comment: instead of splitting on `//` (everything), split on all whitespace `/\s+/` this will only take the elements which are not whitespace; namely your numbers and operators

Comment: `split(' ')` even better as it ignores leading spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, only consider as valid tokens sequences of non-space characters. Second, if a token doesn't look like a number, make sure a handler [exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) in the `%operators` hash. I find [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) and [pop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) more natural when dealing with a stack, but that doesn't really matter;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Turn on autoflush
local $| = 1;

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my %operators = (
    '+' => \&add,
    '-' => \&subtract,
    '*' => \&multiply,
    '/' => \&divide,
);

print 'Enter an expression to evaluate : ';

my $input = <STDIN>;

my @tokens = split ' ', $input;

my @stack;

for my $token (@tokens) {
    if (looks_like_number($token)) {
        push @stack, $token;
    }
    else {
        if (exists $operators{$token}) {
            my $op = $operators{$token};
            my $x = pop @stack;
            my $y = pop @stack;
            push @stack, $op->($x, $y);
        }
        else {
            warn "Unknown token '$token'\n";
        }
    }
}

print "Answer: $stack[-1]\n";

sub add      { $_[0] + $_[1];}
sub multiply { $_[0] * $_[1];}
sub subtract { $_[0] - $_[1];}
sub divide   { $_[0] / $_[1];}
```

Comment: Yes I prefer shift and unshift cause this is like I visualize the stack.